# Are Windows XP Service Packs Cumulative?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, slipstream

I want to make a slipstreamed, bootable Windows XP installation CD, and I have the original installation CD that comes with no service packs.

Are Windows XP service packs cumulative? In order words, do I need to download SP1 and SP2 before I download SP3, or will SP3 suffice? If they are cumulative, this will make the slipstreaming process easier.

Comment: There is over 100 patches since SP3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SP 3 as a start point and add every update released after SP 3. [How to slipstream an XP disc with SP3 and all other updates](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/8053/how-to-slipstream-an-xp-disc-with-sp3-and-all-other-updates) by *David Ludlow* is a step-by-step guide for that using [Updates Downloader, Checker and Add-on Creator](http://xdot.tk) (UDC) script & [nLite](https://www.nliteos.com/download.html).

That said, you should really move on. Support for Windows XP [has ended](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-xp-support).

> After 12 years, support for Windows XP ended April 8, 2014. Microsoft
>   will no longer provide security updates or technical support for the
>   Windows XP operating system. It is very important that customers and
>   partners migrate to a modern operating system such as Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for Windows XP, all Microsoft supplied service packs are cumulative. Service Pack 3 contains all the fixes from the previous service packs.

See this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_pack) and scroll down to "Incremental and cumulative SPs" for more information.